# kotlin simple_list_item_1 onclicklistener not working

Tags: android, listview, kotlin, onitemclicklistener

I am building a shopping list App and this is one of the activities.

Basically the activity takes a database of all locations around the house and extracts a list of the names to create an arrayList of Strings for display.

After that it binds the prepareListView to a variable prepareList and creates an arrayAdapter with a layout of simple_list_item_1.

After attaching the adapter it sets the onItemClicListener.

The Listview works perfectly but I cannot get the onClickListener to work.

I have searched this site and also generally on the internet without finding a solution.  I can get the listener to work with a custom adapter but it is an overkill for what I am trying to do.  Most of the solutions are Java which seems very different to Kotlin in implementing the onClick function.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.prepare)

    // populate the home locations array
    val  prepareHomeLocations = productDatabase!!.getAllHomeLocations()

    // create a reduced array for displaying
    val reducedHomeLocations = ArrayList<String>()
    for (items in prepareHomeLocations.indices) {
        reducedHomeLocations.add(prepareHomeLocations[items].homeArea)
    }

    // bind the listView
    var prepareList = findViewById<ListView>(R.id.prepareListView)

    // create an adapter
    val adapter =
        ArrayAdapter(this@Prepare, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, reducedHomeLocations)

    // attach the adapter
    prepareList.adapter = adapter

    // set the onItemClicListener
    prepareList.setOnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, id ->

        Toast.makeText(this@Prepare, "item Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

Is it that the onClickListener will not work with a simple_list_item_1 view?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Taseer - really appreciated

This got me really puzzled

I had worked all day yesterday and had tried your suggestion along with countless other combinations so unfortunately I posted one of the incorrect variations I tried.  I put it back this morning but to no avail - still the click listener did not work. However, armed with the knowledge that it was the correct code I went searching the Internet once again and found a ListView example at https://android--code.blogspot.com/2018/02/android-kotlin-listview-example.html

I created a new project and copied in the code - it worked perfectly and so I was at least moving forward with working code.

I could not see any significant differences in my code to the one I downloaded and so to make sure I copied the xml and kt code into the activity as a total replacement to the code I had written.  This time it did not work.  Thinking that it must be something to do with the linking of the activities, I started from first principles and did the same with the main activity.  This way, the main activity of the working example and that of the programme I am creating are identical.  Still it did not work !!

The problem was therefore nothing to do with the code as it is identical between the two projects.  I started searching deeper.  First made the two Gradle file and the Manifest file the same and deleted off all the other activities I had created....... still not working!

Finally looked at the last option - Styles and, yipee, I finally managed to trace the cause of the problem.  I had accidentally set the TextView style parent to Widget.AppCompat.AutoCompleteTextView instead of android:Widget.TextView.

So, I loaded the backup of the programme and corrected this mistake and it is now working properly.  I have absolutely no idea why a different style for the colour scheme should block the operation of the on-click listener but I presume that the AutoCompleteTextView style has it's own listener that took priority.

Once again, many thanks for your help

eggie